# Looking for a parse configuration with syntax param (space) value

Tags: c, parsing

guys: In my program in C I need a library to parse a file which is a configuration file. This file has this type of syntax:

```
cmd     "ls"
theme   "current"
```

as you can see is not a INI format...any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, and what is the problem?

Comment: If you want a custom format, you have to write a custom parser. If you want a pre-existing parser, you may consider reformatting your file, translating it. How big is it?

Comment: `fgets()` and `strtok()`.

Comment: It's not my file, I'm trying to parse [/etc/slim.conf](https://github.com/elaird/etc/blob/master/slim.conf) and get some values like "current_theme" or "logfile"

Answer (score 0):

that looks compatible with scanf:

```
scanf(f,"%s\"%[^\"]",key,value);
```

you;re probably going to want to use `m` or size limits after those `%`s

```
char key[20],value[80];
scanf(f,"%20s\"%80[^\"]",key,value);
```

or

```
char *key=NULL,*value=NULL;
scanf(f,"%ms\"%m[^\"]",key,value);
```

Comment: I can go as you pointed Jasen, but I guess I need some loop for parse [this file](https://github.com/elaird/etc/blob/master/slim.conf) and get specific values from "logfile" or "current_theme".

Answer (score 0):

This is valid Lua syntax and so Lua can be used out of the box. You just have to register functions for `cmd` and `theme`.

As a bonus, you get comments and empty lines for free. (And much more, of course.)